# column vice or row vice which is more fast and good method of implementation

Tags: mysql

[image: Which of the table structure is good if the data is static most of the time]

if there are many blank values in a table for each row then does it decrease the speed of the data reading

I am attaching both the table sample for the reference. which one is more performance drive

the data is from MySQL and most of the time the data is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static data always choose the first form. The second is an [EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) and results is rather awkward queries.

When in doubt, write out the SQL for what you are using your table for, and the simplest ones mean that the data is structured well.